# Keep your passport option when applying for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, passports, madrid

I have applied for a tourist visa for the UK at Madrid visa application centre. I have paid for the "keep your passport" option, so I can keep my passport while the application is being processed.

My question is: once you get the visa approved, how does the procedure work? Do I have to get an appointment so that the visa can be applied? Can I do it without an appointment? How long does that take?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @NHB Have you checked the VFS website for this information?

Answer (score 3):

The [VFS Global help page](https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/article-uk-visa-guide.html) explains the process in detail:

> #### 2. Keep Your Passport When Applying
>
> If you need to apply for multiple visas, such as a UK / Schengen combination, or wish to make a short trip while waiting for your UK visa to be processed, you will find the ‘Keep My Passport When Applying’ service at the UK Visa Application Centre very helpful. After enrolling your biometrics and submitting your visa application at the UK visa application centre, if you have opted for this service, your passport is handed back to you.
>
> This is extremely useful if you want to carry on with another country’s visa application formalities, as this service allows you to keep your passport with you.
>
> You can keep your passport with you until the UK embassy makes a decision regarding your visa, one way or the other.
>
> Once the decision is made, you will be called once again to complete the procedures as required by the embassy

The timing of the callback appointment depends on how long it takes for the immigration officers to make their decision and the availabilities of these appointments. Eventually you'll have to go back to the consulate/embassy with your original passport in order for the visa/stamp to be applied on it.

Comment: In Spain it's Teleperformance but the general process should be the same.

Comment: @joernano For the callback appointment, can someone else go in my stead with my passport and get the stamp related formalities done?

Comment: I don't know. I think it's very unlikely, however, that the pick-up could be delegated to another person.